# how do I load test a flash application

Tags: flash, load-testing

Does anyone know a good tool (commercial or free) for stress testing flash applications?

Comment: What kinds of stress tests do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

[Flash Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) may be what you're looking for. It's more for unit and acceptance testing rather than stress testing. I think for stress testing you want to use [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) and simulate the server calls from the Flash application.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get Flash Selenium to work (as Michael Glenn suggested), I'd also recommend you check out my company, BrowserMob, which provides [load testing with real browsers](http://browsermob.com). The browsers are powered by Selenium and, since they are real browsers, run Flash exactly like you'd expect they would.

Comment: just sayin, when I tried to run the instant test on some site, I first got sent to neustar.biz (iirc) and after enabling javascript and retrying, I got lost into a 404 page

Comment: @JonasWielicki Sorry about that. Since I posted this BrowserMob got acquired by Neustar and a redirect might have gone sideways. Hopefully it's fixed now. I don't work there any more but I'll ask someone to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do that with [Microsoft Web Application Stress Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e2c0585a-062a-439e-a67d-75a89aa36495&displaylang=en#Overview) or [Borland SilkPerformer](http://www.borland.com/us/products/silk/silkperformer/index.html).

You might want to take a look how Adobe is doing [their stress testing](http://www.adobe.com/special/under_the_hood/report3/).

Answer (score 1):

[AppLoader](http://www.nrgglobal.com/apploader) is Protocol Independent.  No separate test licenses for each of the applications used in your enterprise. Because AppLoader looks at bitmaps on the screen, it can be used to test all applications accessible from a GUI front end.

Answer (score 0):

I have found  a really nice service at http://www.cloudpuncher.com/index.shtml